# Can't read mocked InputStream from mocked GridFSDBFile

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, junit, mockito

I am using JUnit, Mockito and Spring's MockMvc to write a unit test which tests the ability to read a GridFSDBFile from service, then write to a response's content.
It can't read the mocked InputStream from mocked GridFSDBFile, but it can read the mocked length?! Where am I wrong?

**Controller:**

```java
...
@Controller
public class FileReadController {

    @Autowired
    private IFileService fileService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/v0/files/{fileid}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody void read(@PathVariable String fileid, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {
        GridFSDBFile file = this.fileService.find(fileid);
        res.setContentLength((int) file.getLength());
        IOUtils.copy(file.getInputStream, res.getOutputStream());

        System.out.println("file's length:" + file.getLength());
        System.out.println("file's content:" + IOUtils.toString(file.getInputStream()));
    }
}
...
```

**ControllerTest:**

```java
...
public class FileReadControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private FileService mockFileService;
    @InjectMocks
    private FileReadController mockReadController;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(mockReadController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReadSuccessfully() throws Exception {

        GridFSDBFile file = createFile();
        String expectedString = IOUtils.toString(file.getInputStream());

        when(mockFileService.find(anyString())).thenReturn(file);

        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/v0/files/fileId"))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(content().string(expectedString));

    }

    private GridFSDBFile createFile() throws IOException {

        String content = "this is the fake content";

        GridFSDBFile file = mock(GridFSDBFile.class);
        when(file.getInputStream()).thenReturn(IOUtils.toInputStream(content));
        when(file.getLength()).thenReturn((long) content.length());
        when(file.getContentType()).thenReturn("application/x-rpm");

        return file;
    }

}
...
```

and it's fail:

```java
java.lang.AssertionError: Response content expected:<this is the fake content> but was:<>
```

**Console Output:**

```java
...
file's length:24
file's content:          //nothing
...
```

When I investigate file.getInputStream() in debug mode, it shows something in there:

```java
file.getInputStream();
    - buf   [116, 104, 105, 115, 32, ...]
    - count 24
    - mark  0
    - pos   24
```

So I can't figure out why I can't convert this inputStream to String even there is content in it...

**some dependencies**

```java
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:0.5.0.M4
org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2
junit:junit:4.11
org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5
org.springframework:spring-test:3.2.4.RELEASE
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be caused by incorrect initialization of mockReadController. You call MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this) right in the beginning of setUp() method when  mockReadController is expected to be null. So it is impossible to inject you mockFileService into it.

Try something like this:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mockReadController = Mockito.mock(FileReadController.class);    
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    //your other stuff
}
```